# Parameter wont filter report SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

For some reason my Parameter won't filter my report according. I have 3 datasets for 2 different tables. One dataset is Project, one is for Issue and the last one is the dataset the parameter will be referring to for values called SelectProject with the following values added:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectName, ID
FROM            Project
```

Parameter Name is: SelectProject.

My Projects dataset looks like this:

```
SELECT        Project.ProjectCode, Project.ProjectName, 
              Project.ProjectDescription, Project.ID, ProjectSponsorIDText, 
FROM            Project
WHERE        (Project.ID IN (@SelectProject))
```

The issue arises with my Issues dataset.

```
SELECT        Issue.IssueName, Issue.ID, Issue.RelatedRisk, 
              Issue.Project, Issue.RaisedBy, Issue.Description, 
              Issue.Impact, Issue.ImpactDescription
FROM            Issue 
INNER JOIN
                         Project ON Issue.ID=Project.ID
WHERE        (Project.ID IN (@SelectProject))
```

For some reason, it doesnt not filter my issues table according and just leaves me with am empty table. 
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should join your issues using the Issue.Project field:

```
SELECT        Issue.IssueName, Issue.ID, Issue.RelatedRisk, 
              Issue.Project, Issue.RaisedBy, Issue.Description, 
              Issue.Impact, Issue.ImpactDescription
FROM            Issue 
INNER JOIN Project ON Issue.Project = Project.ID
WHERE         Project.ID = @SelectProject
```

Comment: You better keep the IN operator in your code of the original query

Comment: Ahhh. I knew i was joining it on the wrong field. Thanks for that